# Tableau Gender Infographic Visual

Tags: tableau-api

I am hoping to create a visual to show the mix in attendance from the different countries listed similar to the one below. Is this possible with Tableau? Is it possible to show partial shading (i.e. GER was 5% higher than CAN but it doesnt show here).

My data is currently set up with a very basic percent of total chart broken out by region

[image]

Comment: Yes to the chart above (countries on Row, Gender on Shape/Color, with some dimension on detail that breaks data into 10% chunks of the population - so it may be easier to do some data shaping first in Tableau Prep Builder. No unfortunately for partial shading if you mean shapes that are part man/part woman or part pink/part black. At least not without lots of effort. Simply to just divide your data into finer grained blocks